# storing Hexadecimal value in Java properties file without "\"

Tags: java, properties

I'm trying to add hexadecimal value in a property file, the value is getting stored but i can see a **"\"** getting appended, which I don't want,

test.properties

```
#
#Fri Jun 07 21:18:49 GMT+05:30 2013
test=fe\:fe
```

the Java file

```
public class PropertySave {
    private static File s_file;
    private static Properties s_properties = new Properties();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadProperties();
        s_properties.setProperty("test", "fe:fe");
        saveProperties();
    }
    private static void saveProperties() {
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        try {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(s_file);
            s_properties.store(fout, "");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            if (fout != null) {
                try {
                    fout.close();
                } catch (final IOException ioe2) {
                    ioe2.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static void loadProperties() {
        s_file = new File("test.properties");
        if ((!s_file.exists()) || (!s_file.isFile())) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(s_file);
            s_properties.load(fin);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            if (fin != null) {
                try {
                    fin.close();
                } catch (final IOException ioe2) {
                    ioe2.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In java file the **s_properties.setProperty("test", "fe:fe");** the output in property file is different(test.properties) **fe:fe** this i want to ignore as this property file is input to other system in **"C"** Language because of which my things are not working,

What Should I do to make sure the input in java file and output in properties file will same

Comment: The colon is a special character to the properties logic -- it is the separator between key and value in the properties file.  So if you want a value with a colon in it, it must be stored in the properties file in "escaped" form.  If you don't want this, don't use the Java properties mechanism to write the file.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, escaped form example like ? if i give this "fe\\:fe" the output is "fe\\\:fe".  my input and output must match,I cannot change the java properties mechanism for now

Comment: You want too much.  You're asking the properties mechanism to do something it's not designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider encoding the hexidecimal values in a known way and decoding them in both C and Java.

One technique is to precede the hexidecimal value with "0x" and use all upper case for the digits.
If you use this technique, you will need some way to signal the end of a hexidecimal number.
I suggest a space character (' ') or end of line.

With this technique, your property will look like this:

`test=0xFEFE`

The string "Blam07kapow" where 07 is a hex number would look like this:

`Blam0x07 kapow`

Comment: thanks, Looks like the PropertyClass replace all the occurences of ":" with "\:" regardless of hexadecimal value, which causing problem to the extrenal system like C, is there any way for workaround

Answer (score 0):

The Properties class stores : with a preceding \ in order to ensure that it will load the proper value again when you use the load method.  If you want to be able to load in this properties file back into java later on, then I'm afraid you are stuck with the escape character in your properties file.  See [java.util.Properties documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thanks preceding \ throws compilation error " s_properties.setProperty("test", "fe\:fe");" throws compilation error

Comment: Well, if you precede the : with a \ in the actual code, then it thinks you are trying to use a Java escape character, but it likely does not have an escape sequence for \:   The \: is only an escape character for storing and loading properties from a file.

Comment: If you don't absolutely need a colon in the properties (say you are reading the properties file into another programming language), then I would suggest going with DwB's solution, as most languages understand hexadecimal values in the notation 0x123DEF

Comment: Thanks, It looks like the ":" is replace by "\:" by the property class, for all value not specific to the hexadecimal, for external system, the value will always wrong is there any way to upgarde the property value there itself